# RunAsInvoker causing errors to occur on certain installers

Tags: batch-file, installation, cmd, windows-installer

I am using a batch file to prevent the UA prompt from showing up to install programs:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
```

But recently I have noticed that more and more installers throw errors like:

```
Error opening files for writing: https://...
```

I have tested running the same installation file entering the admin password (so without using the batch file) and it works perfectly fine.

Why do such errors occur, what has it to do with the environment variable mentioned above, and is there a way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the complete error?

Comment: It shows the cancel/retry/ignore box, i can skip that file but the error occurs on all files.

Comment: RunAsInvoker compatibility mode can only prevent the elevation prompt; it does not grant the process the actual administrative privileges. If your account does not have priviligies to write to a folder like "Program Files" you can get those errors.